# NodeJS cross communication for running nodes

Tags: node.js, network-programming

I want to develop a program where my NodeJS nodes can communicate back and forth without having a dedicated host.

All node instances are running on different computers on my local network.

For example, I have my computer running a Node application on port 30001 (and the firewall is not blocking). I setup a Raspberry Pi that runs another node application on port 3001.

Without having to know either the Raspberry Pi nor my computer's IP addresses, how can they find each other? FYI, I have tried using the arp command, but its cache isn't updated fast enough.

Here is some expected behavior:

```
mycomputer>node index.js
pi>node index.js

mycomputer>
Found '<pi or IP>' running on port 3001
Sending default greeting 'Welcome to Node friend network. My name is mycomputer'

pi>
Found '<mycomputer or IP>' running on port 3001
Sending default greeting 'Welcome to Node friend network. My name is pi'
Message from '<mycomputer or IP>': Welcome to Node friend network. My name is mycomputer.

mycomputer>
Message from '<pi or IP>': Welcome to Node friend network. My name is pi
```

Comment: What you are looking for is called "network resource discovery".  There are a bunch of competing ways/protocols to do it.  One such scheme is [Bonjour](https://github.com/watson/bonjour) (created by Apple and used by their products).  You would need to find a scheme that is supported on whatever platforms you are using.  The general idea is that services register themselves and then other services can find them.  Using a discovery service that is already present in your system allows you to avoid creating a new server at a known IP for this purpose.

Comment: You may also want to read about [mDNS](http://agnat.github.io/node_mdns/user_guide.html).